# help with two lines of this song

Tags: translation, meaning

These are two lines of the song ["believe"](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-73852.html) of Kalafina...

1-what means 巡{めぐ}り来る時の中{なか}で?

> 巡{めぐ}り来る時の中{なか}で出{で}会{あ}った君といた僕を信{しん}じている

2-it is normal to change the order in songs (蒼{あお}い日々を切{き}り開{ひら}け)?

> 切{き}り開{ひら}け蒼{あお}い日々を

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this definition for 巡り来る:

> チャンスや運などが自分の元に来ること

So, it's the coming of a good thing. So 巡り来る時の中で would be something like "in the time to come", with an overtone of hope and optimism. Hopefully more senior members can verify or deny this.

As to the second question, I'd go so far as to say that changing the order is common not only in songs, but also casual speech. Off the top of my head, I immediately think of this verse from ZARD's 「負けないで」：

> 「追いかけて遥かな夢を」"Chase after distant dreams"

It's not usually so dramatic in casual speech, though. It's almost like people say a complete sentence, then realize that one important, clarifying piece of information was left out.

> 暑いね、大阪は。 "It's hot isn't it? In Osaka."

The thing I usually hear moved to the end is the topic marked by は, I think. But, I think any kind of clarifying information can be added as long as you don't go crazy and talk like a Japanese Yoda all the time.

Comment: Since the subject of 巡り来る is 時 instead of チャンスや運など and it's not 巡り来た, this 巡り来る means for seasons to circulate.

Comment: @user4092 and what does it mean in this context?

Comment: I personally don't sense really deep meanings because that whole 巡り来る時の中で is a cliche in songs that often modifies events like encounter with a lover and 巡り来る itself is also another cliche for 時. It's natural for Japanese people to consider time as something that circulates like seasons. So, it's even close to kind of tautology like "flowing time".